# Pan and Zoom Tree in Vega

Tags: looker-studio, vega-lite, vega

Looking to be able to Pan and Zoom a tree diagram in Vega.

I have the example code working for my data but there is too much of it to be able to reasonably display in even a large chart. Therefore I am looking for a way to pan and zoom.

I have searched Google and SO, but there are zero posts about panning and zooming a tree.

Code used:

````
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "transform": [{
        "type": "nest",
        "generate": true,
        "keys": ["$dimension1"]
        },
        {
          "type": "tree",
          "method": "tidy",
          "size": [{"signal": "height"}, {"signal": "width - 20"}],
          "separation": true,
          "as": ["y", "x", "depth", "children"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "links",
      "source": "default",
      "transform": [
        { "type": "treelinks" },
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "orient": "horizontal",
          "shape": "diagonal"
        }

      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "default", "field": "depth"},
      "range": {"scheme": "datastudio20"}
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "links"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "path": {"field": "path"},
          "stroke": {"value": "#ccc"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "default"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "size": {"value": 100},
          "stroke": {"value": "#fff"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "depth"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "default"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {"signal":"datum.$dimension0 || datum.key || 'Customer'"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 12},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "dx": {"signal": "datum.children ? -7 : 7"},
          "align": {"signal": "datum.children ? 'right' : 'left'"},
          "opacity": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you:

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQXEACOAA8kCHABs4OtgDMdAYSSLMCmkl0mkATzYNMEHZbaKOkg64mzyALQmNOIA1jqyzmSKRhbWMDRwyYqwNFBIJvFImFTSIADuNLL0aABsAAx1MvA0ZFi1DTI4SLIJ4mRoAjJI3mwQNABecGigmO44U+ih4lMyik6TaJb5EHAAvjJjZOLbaADaoMcICxhspIqlEmegcKTiPmggAFSoCF47t5lSnBxFAwtcYAD7vtnq93uhvr8GP9vECQWCPmYkKQQNCQC9gXCvj8-nBZGwypIZMDQfIPjszFBMDipDCCRAPgiSQwcKiadc1pidjiALq4y7XfTJPorEDc2RFa6nRo6CpVGDC5kXIzXdxSsgyuUKj6nZqtTBSHR1DVi7UfMkU0rEfIMBbiBgmEwyR6oc542Hs9CInb2ymynDyxwffTuAAUAEoRTarlGoAx7jInSYXWg3R6vRpffi3gGQEHSeTQ4bI+gIFEoHAY-oyQgE7tRSyQOKPu5U+mQJns6hc56QN7C-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-radegHIe2r6l1hq0dARjWProlHlfBw2OZ2-Gfvh-7uKN4UTcctH2Ns8mNixmr0CgNxjBjAAmOodFWwWYZbC04poho6hXGQIxQdybPXEBv2AmdFG6uQin4Sw3DWEQxFDb8XAgAKnITpCayLtRLHcUoYjgWv0EqUoujWN4AGkG4+VuCSgivk7WGUrnoMIyc6xWQCUtRZHcJSnrGDYE-HjPuaZXFl6vdaYHGyO6hFA44Fbop1DHimM+CqZ+qQANThAWuZH0Up5FUGBShyExZDbkBrP7xre5kSwGQP5RlKBvdADV9Brw7L-SB-8QCAIkrIbsoCz7dkauVRO1woixHZAcLwgV0ApxlEXd8pdQJzGuEQ7BMRcHyzuugbkEAU5GD7hQjE0QYhdGqF6ZQvd0DvQmBIYokkDgwCQA+dqdCJ5KQSEgMgEh8hz36jBesyUyYGBwPcGseQzDKWMjojSFoIyfkoCouAlB3CtjwReOAAANdR+hNF0gMcpVSBizLGIQKY-B9ZKD6Cscnew+pMBqMkRorR0EXFGRMoYwomATHFEUMEixATEnBPsWExxESYmuJiR4ooCSgkAT8a2NsbYDgGJvhVD4oITA8UQmw9A2C4D2FKHqBYHVYCIHAnI5AT1mxIGiGTOOHwiH+SAUgnqL8nqTEUGwIKP49guyTm49SpRZnzNQFsEwOxY6OUGRoG6CsM5Nkev1dpp9jlRgubsdG3YYnrMyJs7Zuy5D7KGZIsBd8qrnJcPqS59C743PKaWewNDyESJAFw1+AC5ll1ACMppHD2T9WpOiSRtNQDQrJgg4B6BsXKO-GweuZMBzXAAMRQCpTiW5uJ+4QHcAgJgbARHwLhcMrOozB5PW9ioBZIU0W0jCW8QEnyJgdP7LuNAu9CVzJJZIslHxyWWBVTSj2MlQCP0+QYqMDyAETJAf1RunS1noH0Ws-ViDkH9UAR6MeOqvYsvqfAg1Uzqi0rpY05O6DYWPUkYigeqd+q8p5KgC+VI0RCueCKrRMx0GSNxZMzBT1-BvAAMritJVK1AABOfqTBr4SWiBKxVgZKiyDMGq56EqtUmsreAvVLqrXgKesayJpq76NsTda2OtapEZ08ZQd+n9gR4X1gAdkYjocdT18i3QBRPQdw625jqUsoM0Skp1KTMJYTASivRdCgHQNtXyaI0tuaKIAA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "An example of Cartesian layouts for a node-link diagram of hierarchical data.",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 600,
  "padding": 5,
  "autosize": {"type": "none", "resize": false},
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "hover",
      "on": [
        {"events": "*:mouseover", "encode": "hover"},
        {"events": "*:mouseout", "encode": "leave"},
        {"events": "*:mousedown", "encode": "select"},
        {"events": "*:mouseup", "encode": "release"}
      ]
    },
    {"name": "xrange", "update": "[0, width]"},
    {"name": "yrange", "update": "[height, 0]"},
    {
      "name": "down",
      "value": null,
      "on": [{"events": "mousedown", "update": "xy()"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "xcur",
      "value": null,
      "on": [{"events": "mousedown", "update": "slice(xdom)"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "ycur",
      "value": null,
      "on": [{"events": "mousedown", "update": "slice(ydom)"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "delta",
      "value": [0, 0],
      "on": [
        {
          "events": [
            {
              "source": "window",
              "type": "mousemove",
              "consume": true,
              "between": [
                {"type": "mousedown"},
                {"source": "window", "type": "mouseup"}
              ]
            }
          ],
          "update": "down ? [down[0]-x(), y()-down[1]] : [0,0]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "anchor",
      "value": [0, 0],
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "wheel",
          "update": "[invert('xscale', x()), invert('yscale', y())]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "zoom",
      "value": 1,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "wheel!",
          "force": true,
          "update": "pow(1.001, event.deltaY * pow(16, event.deltaMode))"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "xdom",
      "update": "slice(xext)",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "[xcur[0] + span(xcur) * delta[0] / width, xcur[1] + span(xcur) * delta[0] / width]"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "zoom"},
          "update": "[anchor[0] + (xdom[0] - anchor[0]) * zoom, anchor[0] + (xdom[1] - anchor[0]) * zoom]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ydom",
      "update": "slice(yext)",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "[ycur[0] + span(ycur) * delta[1] / height, ycur[1] + span(ycur) * delta[1] / height]"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "zoom"},
          "update": "[anchor[1] + (ydom[0] - anchor[1]) * zoom, anchor[1] + (ydom[1] - anchor[1]) * zoom]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {"name": "size", "update": "clamp(20 / span(xdom), 1, 1000)"}
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "tree",
      "url": "data/flare.json",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "stratify", "key": "id", "parentKey": "parent"},
        {
          "type": "tree",
          "method": {"signal": "'tidy'"},
          "size": [{"signal": "height"}, {"signal": "width+100"}],
          "separation": {"signal": "true"},
          "as": ["y", "x", "depth", "children"]
        },
        {"type": "extent", "field": "x", "signal": "xext"},
        {"type": "extent", "field": "y", "signal": "yext"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "links",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "treelinks", "signal": "upstream"},
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "orient": "horizontal",
          "shape": {"signal": "'diagonal'"},
          "sourceY": {"expr": "scale('yscale', datum.source.y)"},
          "sourceX": {"expr": "scale('xscale', datum.source.x)"},
          "targetY": {"expr": "scale('yscale', datum.target.y)"},
          "targetX": {"expr": "scale('xscale', datum.target.x)"}
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {"scheme": "magma"},
      "domain": {"data": "tree", "field": "depth"},
      "zero": true
    },
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "zero": false,
      "domain": {"signal": "xdom"},
      "range": {"signal": "xrange"}
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "zero": false,
      "domain": {"signal": "ydom"},
      "range": {"signal": "yrange"}
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "links"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {"path": {"field": "path"}, "stroke": {"value": "#ccc"}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "tree"},
      "clip": true,
      "encode": {
        "enter": {"size": {"value": 100}, "stroke": {"value": "#fff"}},
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "x"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "y"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "depth"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "tree"},
      "clip": true,
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {"field": "name"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 9},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "x"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "y"},
          "dx": {"signal": "datum.children ? -7 : 7"},
          "align": {"signal": "datum.children ? 'right' : 'left'"},
          "opacity": {"signal": "1"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```